# How can i move multiple PictureBox togheter?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have 44 picturebox in my form, and i would like to move these together (at the same time) but i don't know how to do that whitout writing "picturebox.left+=10" for every picturebox... so there is a fastest way to do that ?

Comment: Can they all be put into a single container (e.g., `Panel`)?

Comment: The duplicate question shows you how to find them, then you just use a simple loop to move them all.